# Automatically add macros for C in git patch

Tags: c++, c, git, gerrit

For c/cpp code I want to add all my newly added changes inside a macro and removed changes in the else part.

e.g. for the below patch

```
diff --git a/test.c b/test.c
index a35d23a..5ee498a 100644
--- a/test.c
+++ b/test.c
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main() {
-    printf("Old line");
+    printf("New line");
     return 0;
 }
```

modified to

```
diff --git a/test.c b/test.c
index a35d23a..668d2e0 100644
--- a/test.c
+++ b/test.c
@@ -1,6 +1,10 @@
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main() {
+#ifdef MODIFIED
+    printf("New line");
+#else
     printf("Old line");
+#endif
     return 0;
 }
```

Or

```
diff --git a/test.c b/test.c
index a35d23a..d05f7d1 100644
--- a/test.c
+++ b/test.c
@@ -1,6 +1,11 @@
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main() {
+#ifdef MODIFIED
+    printf("New line");
+#endif
+#ifndef MODIFIED
     printf("Old line");
+#endif
     return 0;
 }
```

I tried searching if there is some inbuilt tool for doing this. Unfortunately could not find one.

Can someone please help.
TIA

Comment: Seems like a job for `sed` or `awk`.

Comment: Perhaps you could use and patch the [GPP](https://github.com/logological/gpp) preprocessor to fit your needs.

Comment: `sed` or `gawk` won't cut the cheese. This needs to swallow `git diff` output, then extract the original source file, and intelligently transmogrify it. This is beyond the powers of `sed` and `gawk`, but this should be doable in a higher-order scripting language that has good text processing features, specifically `perl`. `python` should also be able to handle it, but the script will end up being three-four times longer than the comparable `perl` script (typical). To the extent that this is asking for pointers or software recommendations: that's off-topic, of course.

Comment: By the way, build your tool to generate this on the fly from a commit and its first parent, don't check in the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is built into `diff`, at least on Linux and macOS (it is not in the POSIX specification for `diff`). From https://linux.die.net/man/1/diff:

> `-D NAME` `--ifdef=NAME`
>
> Output merged file to show '#ifdef NAME' diffs.

For a POSIX `diff` without this feature, `diff -U 99999999 FileA FileB` will produce the entire contents of reasonable files, and then a simple script can insert a `#if defined !Name` where `-` starts in the first column, a `#else` where a `-` changes to a `+`, a `#if defined Name` where `+` starts without a preceding `-`, and a `#endif` where `+` or `-` ends, along with removing the headers and the leading character of each line (a space for unchanged lines). That leaves the groups of lines reversed from what you show, so it has the old lines first and then the new lines. If that is not acceptable, you could swap the order of the files on the `diff` command line and change the senses of `-` and `+`.